# What is the use of cstmt.registerOutParameter(2, Types.VARCHAR);

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, jdbc, callable-statement

I'm using a Stored Procedure(InOut).. im little bit confused with the line cstmt.registerOutParameter(2,Types.VARCHAR);//why we write registerOutParameter and is it necessary to write the data type of that parameter like Types.VARCHAR

My Stored Procedure

```
 CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Rinout`(in p1  int, inOut p2 varchar(25))
    begin
    UPDATE sush SET address = p2 WHERE id = p1;
    SELECT address INTO p2 FROM sush WHERE id = p1;
    end$$
    DELIMITER ;
```

My Servlet Code

```
package com.ravi;

import java.sql.*;

public class Spinout
{ static
    {
    //STEP 1 : Registering The Driver Class

    try
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Unable To Load The Driver class");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Connection con = null;

    CallableStatement cstmt = null;

    try
    {
        //Database Credentials

        String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ravi";

        String username = "root";

        String password = "root";

        //STEP 2 : Creating The Connection Object

        con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, username, password);
            //STEP 3 : Creating The CallableStatement Object

            cstmt = con.prepareCall("{call Rinout(?, ?)}");

            //Setting IN Parameters

            cstmt.setInt(1, 1);

            cstmt.setString(2, "WGL");

            //Registering OUT parameters

            cstmt.registerOutParameter(2, Types.VARCHAR);

            //STEP 4 : Executing The CallableStatement

            cstmt.execute();

            //Retrieving OUT parameter

            String grade = cstmt.getString(2);

            System.out.println(grade);
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            //STEP 5 : Closing The DB Resources

            //Closing the CallableStatement object

            try
            {
                if(cstmt!=null)
                {
                    cstmt.close();
                    cstmt=null;
                }
            }
            catch (SQLException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //Closing the Connection object

            try
            {
                if(con!=null)
                {
                    con.close();
                    con=null;
                }
            }
            catch (SQLException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above is working fine but I want to know why we are using cstmt.registerOutParameter(2,Types.VARCHAR);

Comment: not enough context here can you add all the stored procedure please.

Comment: Added my Stored Procedure as well as Servlet Code

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 good reasons why an `OUT` parameter needs to be registered:

- All bind parameters need to be bound by a value. If you don't explicitly register the `OUT` parameter, then the JDBC driver wouldn't know what to do with the `?` that hasn't been bound by an `IN` parameter. The driver might not know the procedure ahead of calling it, so it would send a `NULL` value to the server where it can't bind anything. Of course, a different marker could have been invented for `OUT` parameters, other than `?`, but that wasn't done.
- Some drivers may require knowing in advance what buffers to allocate before receiving results from the server

In principle, it's possible for a driver to make this optional, despite what the [JDBC spec says](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/CallableStatement.html#registerOutParameter(int,int)):

> All OUT parameters must be registered before a stored procedure is executed.

Ultimately, I think this is just how JDBC (and ODBC) were defined, and it has always worked sufficiently well. I'm not sure if it's possible to know *exactly* why the requirement was added to the spec, if you hadn't been sitting in the specific meeting where it was decided.